# Unable to proxy interface-implementing method AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests.setApplicationContext

Tags: spring

After upgrading to Spring 4.3.14 I suddenly begun to receive a warning:

```
2018-04-03 WARN  [main] framework.CglibAopProxy.doValidateClass():
 Unable to proxy interface-implementing method [public final void
 org.springframework.test.context.junit4.AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests
 .setApplicationContext(org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext)]
 because it is marked as final: Consider using interface-based JDK
 proxies instead!
```

If I interpret this correctly, Spring can't create a proxy of it's own class, `AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests` because one of the methods is marked `final`.

But how do I resolve this?